# Hide access VBA code window after code execution

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have written a function to dynamically create code in VBA. When I run the function, the VBA module shows on the screen to the users and does not close after execution. Is there something I can do to not show the VBA code to the user when I run my function or a method to hide the VBA window after execution?

The code I run is:

````
    'create textbox
    Set txt = CreateControl(frm, acLabel, acDetail, "", "", x, y, w * cmToTwip, h * cmToTwip)
    txt.BorderStyle = 1
    txt.borderColor = borderColor
    txt.BorderWidth = 3
    txt.BackStyle = 0
    txt.ForeColor = 0
    txt.SpecialEffect = 0
    txt.Vertical = True
    txt.Name = "DELRectangle" & idVogn
    txt.TextAlign = 1
    txt.Caption = " " & text
    
    'add onClick event
    Dim mdl As Module
    Set mdl = Forms(frm).Module
    Dim lngReturn As Long
    lngReturn = mdl.CreateEventProc("click", txt.Name)
    mdl.InsertLines lngReturn + 1, "call handleClickOnWagenverfolgung(" & idVogn & ")"```
````

Comment: Try: `Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False`. Actually, that probably doesn't close the window, just makes it hidden. Sorry, I tried `.Close` and just errors.

Comment: While this can be done through WinAPI, dynamic modification of modules should be avoided whenever possible. It seems in this case you can just set `txt.OnClick`  to `"=handleClickOnWagenverfolgung(" & idVogn & ")"` and avoid the issue.

Comment: If you create a module in code, normally you need to compile the VBA project as well, or eventually you will start getting errors. Erik's approach above is the way to go.